# Is it safe to add extra-fields to standard PrestaShop tables?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm creating my own store (not module to distribute, just for my own use), and I'm trying to keep hands off the core to be able to upgrade in future, so I use modules or overrides for extra-functionality.

But I need some more data in standart PS tables (product, addres, and so on).

So my question:

**is it safe to add new fields to standart tables?**

I keep in mind that PrestaShop upgrade installer could add new fields into tables too, so I give very specific names to avoid the treat of naming collision. **But I wonder if upgrade installer could re-create some tables and loose my fields (maybe with converting standart data to the new format, but loosing my extra-data).**

Yes, I can create a module, my own table with extra-data and use insert/update/delete hooks to keep my data consistent, or to do the same in override of each model classes, but I'm looking for more lightweight way to add data (but to keep the core clean and upgradable).

Thanks in advance for your oppinion and any advices.

Comment: I think you're fine with extra fields. It's highly unlikely that tables would ever be recreated. But if you really need or want to be 100% sure then hooks and extra tables will have to be used. Otherwise when you're upgrading do like I do which is make upgrade first on development copy and then on live site if everything checks out ok.

Comment: I'm trying to find a ballance between being 100% sure and not to do a lot of extra work, neither when developing nor later when I could have to rewrite my code due to conflict :)  Anyway, thanks for answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're switching major versions (e.g. 1.6 -> 1.7), that shouldn't be a problem. I haven't seen any new table fields added in the 1.6 versions at any point.

Adding extra fields is standard practice. Every shop needs something done custom. Just add the fields that you need and make a override for that class with the new fields, this will be the most efficient in loading the data.

You can always add SQL table column comments, describe the fields that you've added there.

Don't forget to make regular backups so you don't have to worry.

Even if a conflict arises, you can always prefix you table column pretty easily and do a search and replace in your code files.

Comment: thanks for answer. I know not so much about Prestashop-specific best-practices for now, so your information is very useful.

Comment: btw, and what about major versions compability? I've choosen Presta for one key reason - better retrocompability between versions then other opensorce estore engines provide. I hope it was right choice? :)

Comment: Personally I'd advise against migration between major versions, e.g. 1.6 -> 1.7. Usually there are too many version specific modules (e.g. 3rd party modules designed for 1.6) which have no migration path. Ecommerce shop is much more complicated than say WP blog, people just usually stick to what they have and try to make money using it

Comment: Yes, many store owners dont want to upgrade bacause they dont need new features, but I always thought that the key reason to upgrade is security improvement, no?

Comment: Are there some significant security improvements in 1.7?

Comment: I can't comment much on 1.7 because I haven't tried it out yet. Security are planned for 1.6.x.x too until 2018